# How do I define a global variable in a function that can be accessed by other functions (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript

The user is passing a value to a function and I'm trying to assign that value to a global variable but can't figure out how to do it.

```
var a;    

function changeValue(newValue)    {
     a = newValue;
}

alert("Value of 'a' outside the function " + a); //I want this to output the value of newValue
```

Comment: `window.a = "hello I am the new value of the global a";` <-- if you need an "a" instance in changeValue and a global "a" variable. or just what you did and call the function.

Comment: This works very well. Now you just have to call your function!

Comment: @briosheje I'm very new to JS. Do you think you could elaborate on your explanation, please?

Comment: @user3767997 : Edit: I'm, faster with a comment --> All you did is absolutely perfect, however you have a function (changeValue), but you are never calling it, just add this: `changeValue(15);` **before** the alert, and you will notice that the value of `a` will become 15, this is just what you need to know right now :). Everything you did above is correct anyway, you just forgot to call the function!

Comment: [Seems to work fine.](http://jsfiddle.net/nxnu7509/)

Comment: @briosheje Oh wow. I should have known that. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your function works fine, you simply need to call it:

```
var a;    

function changeValue(newValue)    {
     a = newValue;
}

changeValue(100); // Function call changes the value of a to 100

alert("Value of 'a' outside the function " + a); // 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
var a;
b = 0;

function changeValue(newValue) {
    a = newValue;
    b = newValue;
}
changeValue('a');
changeValue('b');
alert("Value of 'a' outside the function " + a);
alert("Value of 'b' outside the function " + b);
```

Hope this help.